# Easiest way to obtain MeshRegion from CountryData

Tags: computational-geometry, geographics

What is the easiest way to obtain `MeshRegion` objects from `CountryData` that I can use in geographic computations?

For example, this *does not* work for me:

```
reg = DiscretizeGraphics @ CountryData[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "Polygon"];
RegionBounds[reg]

(* {{-2.75903*10^6, 1.7744*10^6}, {-5.70806*10^6, -3.48795*10^6}, {2.69158*10^6, 4.8185*10^6}} *)
```

I want to get mesh regions like the hardcoded USA region in the "Applications" section in [`RegionMember`'s function page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html.en). (I.e. such mesh objects for other countries.)

With the referenced hardcoded region object, `reg`, we get:

```
RegionBounds[reg]
(* {{-124.733, -66.9498}, {25.1246, 49.3845}} *)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take any geo entity with polygon information and get its geo polygon:

```
geopol = Entity["Country", "Greenland"]["Polygon"]
```

The result is a Polygon[GeoPosition[...]] object that represents the actual (non-projected) shape of the region, and can be used in any of the Geo functions, in particular in GeoGraphics.

A 2D MeshRegion object with no geo information requires a choice of projection. Such object will be usable only in maps of the chosen projection. We can project the geo polygon (say to the Mercator projection) with

```
mercpol = GeoGridPosition[geopol, "Mercator"]
```

and then you can construct a 2D MeshRegion object in several ways, say

```
mercmesh = DiscretizeGraphics[mercpol]
```

Then this fits well in a Mercator map, but not for example in an equirectangular map:

```
{GeoGraphics[{Red, mercmesh}, GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Mercator"],
 GeoGraphics[{Red, mercmesh}, GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"]}
```

[image]

However, the original geo polygon will be correctly placed in any projection:

```
{GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Red], geopol}, GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Mercator"],
 GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Red], geopol}, GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jose -- very insightful!

Answer (score 5):

The key is using the cartographic projection "Equirectangular".

```
r4 = CountryData["UnitedStates", {"Polygon", "Equirectangular"}]
Head[r4]
r5 = MeshRegion[r4]
Region[r5, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
RegionBounds[r5]
```

> {{-124.733, -66.9498}, {25.1246, 49.3845}}

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I accepted your answer and then switched the acceptance to Jose's answer -- that one explains the motivation behind the observed behavior and it is more "universal."

Comment: I definitely learned from it. `RegionBounds[mercmesh]` produces a slightly different result for "Mercator" and "Equirectangular" so I still need to learn more about how Mma handles this.